# How do I disable GDM and Graphical User Selection?

Tags: gdm

The new Ubuntu features a completely unkillable GDM. Is there a way to disable it?

It is not enabled in services , the GDM startup script is deleted, it is removed from `update.rc` but it still starts up.

How do I disable GDM and Graphical User Selection?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In Ubuntu 10.04 you should refer to [documentation for Upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/) which handles starting of tasks and services during boot, stopping them during shutdown and supervising them while the system is running.

Upstart handle start of gdm, so you should edit `/etc/init/gdm.conf`

```
sudo vi /etc/init/gdm.conf    # or use nano if vi is unfamiliar
```

Default runlevel in ubuntu 10.04 is 2 so you must change this line

```
stop on runlevel [016]
```

adding "2" in the runlevel list

```
stop on runlevel [0126]
```

Now you can reboot the system.

Answer (score 15):

Do:

```
sudo dpkg-divert  --rename --add /etc/init/gdm.conf
```

Which prints:

```
Adding `local diversion of /etc/init/gdm.conf to /etc/init/gdm.conf.distrib'
```

This will allow you to disable GDM while preventing package upgrades from putting the file back in place **and** allowing the GDM package to upgrade the configuration file.

In the case of 11.x and above lightdm is used instead of GDM.  I instead used the command:

```
sudo dpkg-divert --rename --add /etc/init/lightdm.conf
```

To undo it replace the rename and add with a remove.

Answer (score 11):

Recent versions of Ubuntu are using [upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/) instead of SysV init.

Rename `/etc/init/gdm.conf` to `/etc/init/gdm.disabled`.

For Kubuntu, rename `/etc/init/kdm.conf` to `/etc/init/kdm.disabled`.

Answer (score 10):

I found [this forum thread](http://newyork.ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1305659) to be very helpful:

The solution that I found that worked consistently was post 30 by iscatel:

> well, this disables sound, as a previous post pointed out, but here goes:
>
> in `/etc/default/grub`, comment out (by placing `#` at the start of the line)
>
> ```
> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
> ```
>
> and add
>
> ```
> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="text"
> ```
>
> then
>
> ```
> sudo update-grub2
> ```
>
> this will pass "text" to the kernel at boot time
>   line, disabling gdm.

if it still does not work, you can

```
echo "manual" > /etc/init/gdm.override
```

and try it again. I used Ubuntu 12.04 32-bit server with GNOME core and it worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

Follow the directions of [@freedev on Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/137776/disable-gdm-in-ubuntu-10-04/161544#161544):

```
$ sudo nano /etc/init/gdm.conf
```

And change to:

```
stop on runlevel [0126]
```

Also

```
$ sudo nano /etc/init/tty1.conf
```

And change to:

```
stop on runlevel [!345]
```

Note the missing 2 in the tty1.conf. This is so that you get tty1 up and running and can log on into the first console. No need to mess with GRUB.

Comment: This isn't a threaded forum, so your instruction to "follow the directions above" don't really make sense.  Can you please edit your answer to be more comprehensive?

Comment: @lucian303 stop on runlevel [!345] Didn't get this portion My tty1.conf file contains: start on stopped rc RUNLEVEL=[2345] stop on runlevel [!2345] if i change from "stop on runlevel [!2345]" to "stop on runlevel [!345]" Then both the start on and stop on lines will mean the same. Please explain

Answer (score 3):

The prior answers (as of 20160611) discussing runlevels are only relevant for Ubuntu versions using Upstart. Ubuntu 16.04 switched from upstart to [systemd](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SystemdForUpstartUsers). To boot to console, rather than X, you need to change the default target to boot into from `graphical` to `multi-user`:

```
sudo systemctl enable multi-user.target --force
sudo systemctl set-default multi-user.target
```

Then reboot. To undo this:

```
sudo systemctl set-default graphical.target
```

And then reboot.

Answer (score 2):

You can switch to some other display manager (kdm or xdm being two most widespread alternatives, but there are many more, see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_display_manager_%28program_type%29#Some_available_display_managers)). Just `aptitude install` the one you want to use, run `dpkg-reconfigure gdm` and select it from the list.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just remove it?

```
apt-get remove gdm
```

Answer (score 1):

For those who arrive on this topic, follow the instructions of freedev, but instead of stop gdm on run level 2, you should prevent it from starting on runlevel 2 :

Edit `/etc/init/gdm.conf`

```
$ sudo vi /etc/init/gdm.conf
```

Change this line

```
and runlevel [!06]
```

By this line

```
and runlevel [!026]
```

You can also exclude others run level (3, 4 and 5)